# CheckBoxListView checked all elements

Tags: gxt

i'm using gxt  CheckBoxListView

```
CheckBoxListView<BaseModel> checkList = new CheckBoxListView<BaseModel>();
checkList.setStore(store);
```

i want to `setChecked(true)` for all the models in the store

is there a easy way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the models present in your store (assuming that you have done store.addAll(List yourList);...), set the checked property to  "true"

```
for(ModelData m : store.getModels()) {
    checkList.setChecked(m,true);
}
```